How to run Shell script in active choice parameter?
I am partly new the Jenkins, I want to run a shell script in active choice parameter where I am curling the nexus URL to fetch current images which has been pushed in nexus repository. and those images will given as dynamic parameter to Jenkins job.
right now I have the script to get those into array but for some reason that groovy script isn't working with the active choice parameter block?
how can I ran the shell script within active choice parameter within Jenkins
Explanation on how we can use active choice parameter with shell script.

Could you provide your groovy file as well as Jenkinsfile or Jenkins job configure details? Basically as long as you set the choice parameter with default or additionally selected value, you can retrieve the parameter from script or any other steps you need.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's no different than executing any other shell command in groovy:
def host = 'hostname'.execute().text

This doesn't invoke shell, so all the shell stuff, like IO redirects and parameter expansion doesn't work.
I would encourage you to figure out why requesting a url in groovy doesn't work - groovy can do everything that curl does. Ask another question if you get stuck.
